# Basic set theory proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's been some time since I've done any proof work, and I'm fairly sure that the proof below is incomplete.

I'm trying to prove that a function is 1-to-1 iff $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$.

> proof:
>
> - Assume for some $x$, $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is in $B$.
> - Then $x$ in $A \cap B$ by def of intersection.
> - Assume $f$ is a 1-to-1 function.
> - Then $f(x) =$ one and only one $y$.
> - $f(x)$ maps to the same $y$ even though it is in $A$ and $B$ by def of intersection and 1-to-1.
> - Thus $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$.

Where are the gaps?

Comment: You should quantify $A$ and $B$, I'm assuming you mean for all subsets $A$ and $B$.  Your proof is only one of the directions of the set equality, you've only shown that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.  Third, you're missing the other direction of the if and only if.

Comment: @MichaelBurr No, the RHS is not true for constant functions. If $A$, $B$ are non-empty with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, then for constant $f$ $f(A) \cap f(B)$ is non-empty, but $f(A) \cap f(B)$ is empty.

Comment: @martini Ok, you're right.

Comment: @MichaelBurr The RHS is not true for constant functions. Take for example $A,B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$

Answer (score 1):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose first that $f$ is 1-1.

$(\subseteq)$ Suppose that $x\in A\cap B$.  Then $f(x)\in f(A\cap B)$.  Since $x\in A\cap B$, $x\in A$ and $x\in B$.  Therefore, $f(x)\in f(A)$ and $f(x)\in f(B)$.  Therefore, $f(x)\in f(A)\cap f(B)$.  Hence, $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.

$(\supseteq)$  Suppose that $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$.  So, there is some $x_1\in A$ such that $f(x_1)=y$ and $x_2\in B$ such that $f(x_2)=y$.  Since $f$ is 1-1, and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, it must be that $x_1=x_2$.  Therefore, $x_1\in A\cap B$, so $f(x_1)\in A\cap B$. Hence, $f(A\cap B)\supseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that for all $A$, $B$, $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$.  Let $x$ and $y$ be in your domain such that $f(x)=f(y)=z$.  Then, $f(\{x\}\cap\{y\})=f(\{x\})\cap f(\{y\})$.  Since $f(x)=f(y)$, the RHS=$\{z\}$.  On the other hand, the LHS is $\emptyset$ unless $x=y$ since that is the only case where $\{x\}\cap\{y\}\not=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is not one to on then there are $x\neq y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$. Now set $A=\{x\}$ and $B=\{y\}$ and we have $f(A\cap B)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ but $f(A)\cap f(B)=f(x)$.

Conversely if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is one to one. You can consider $f^{-1}:Im(f)\rightarrow X$ (The inverse function restricted on the image of f, so its well-defined). And use that $f^{-1}(A\cap B)=f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$ for all $A,B\subseteq Y$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ injective $\implies\cdots$

As a consequence of $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\cap B\subseteq B$ we have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)$ and $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(B)$, showing that $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.

So if $f(A\cap B)\neq f(A)\cap f(B)$ for some pair of sets $A,B$ then some $y$ must exist with $y\in f(A)\cap f(B)$ and $y\notin f(A\cap B)$.

Then $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ exist with $f(a)=y=f(b)$ and $a\neq b$ showing that $f$ is not injective.

$\cdots\implies$ $f$ injective.
See the other answers